# Open External Browser from QWebView

Tags: qt, qwebview

I have a "start page" on my application that is just a `QWebView` widget that downloads a page from my server.

When the user clicks on a link I'd like it to open in their default browser, not in the widget.

Is there a way to do this with `QWebView`? Or should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just call QWebPage::setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks) then connect the signal QWebView::linkClicked (const QUrl & url) to a slot, and in the slot execute the browser.
Finding out what the default browser is, is slightly more complicated and depends on which desktop the user is running. The environment variable BROWSER often contains the default.

Or use [QDesktopServices::openUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) [as suggested by gnud in a comment]

Comment: To open a browser, use QDesktopServices::openUrl - http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the links are external, you can just call [QWebView::setOpenExternalLinks(true)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#openExternalLinks-prop) on your QWebView widget. The property is false by default; setting it to true causes external links to open in your default web browser.